# How can I stop missing my dog?

Tags: dogs, death

Yesterday my mom told me my dog Strawberry died. I had her from when she was very young, about 2 months old. From then until now, it's already a few years. I cannot accept the fact. Crying, I cannot stop. Today I stayed in the office with no mind to work, I miss her. Can anyone give me advice on coping with it?

Comment: Grief eventually passes. Make sure that your manager knows why you are so sad. You could always get another dog.

Comment: Thanks,but maybe i can not have another dog,i do not want to have same experience again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and foremost I'm very sorry for your loss, I can't even begin to imagine the wreck I would be if I were to lose one of my cats.

To answer your question there's no magic bullet for the grief of losing a pet - just like there is none for the grief of losing a human loved one. There's no schedule or time limit on these things and different people cope with grief in different ways. What I can say though is that time is a great healer and while it's very raw right now you will feel better as time passes.